# Manipulating 2 image data objects together

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, web, html5-canvas

Basically, I am trying to achieve a high-pass filter for my canvas application. The concept is simple: take the regular image pixels minus the pixels of the same image blurred with a radius of x.
Seems simple, right?

```
var d = pixel.data;
var blurdata = blur(amnt, pixel);
var bd = blurdata.data;
for (var i=0; i<d.length; i+=4) {
    d[i] = 128+(d[i]-bd[i]);
    d[i+1] = 128+(d[i+1]-bd[i+1]);
    d[i+2] = 128+(d[i+2]-bd[i+2]);
}
return pixel;
```

The code is run with 2 parameters, amnt and pixel. Pixel is the ctx.getImageData object, and amnt is the blur radius. The blur function returns an imagedata object as well. The blur code is not the issue though. That works 100% as expected. What the problem is, is that it seems that the d and bd variables are the same. I'm not sure why. When bd[i] is subtracted from d[i] the result is 0, which when added to 128 makes for a completely gray image when the data is put back into the canvas. Oh, and the blurdata and pixel data have the same dimensions.

Any help really appreciated.

Blur function: http://www.files.croar.net/f/9/

Comment: can't. Too many libraries used, and way too much code (like uploading a sample image) to put into one jsfiddle. I've already made sure that the problem is somewhere in this code. It seems like one of the data objects is messing with the other, but I have no clue why.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot on this alone when we can't see how you set up the other variables, etc. My suggestion is just to run `console.log` and see if there is anything that doesn't make sense. Are you remembering to do `canvas.putImageData`?

Comment: Yes. I put the data back and that part works fine too. I console.logged if d[i]==bd[i] and every single pixel returns true, which really confuses me since there should be a noticeable difference between the blurred and regular image.

Comment: Show your implementation of `blur` please.

Comment: @mjkaufer Function I use: files.croar.net/f/9 Adapted from quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html Put in image object, returns image object

Comment: The reason your code isn't working is simple. `blur` is returning `imgdata`. However, `imgdata` is NEVER altered at all, so it returns the same `imgdata` as earlier. So make sure you either re-update `imgdata` or return something different and update the rest of your code.

Comment: This isn't the issue. The blur fn does indeed directly edit the content of imgdata. Problem solved though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is the same because your data is the same. When you blur pixel.data in the blur function it is also changing the values in the array d. What you'll probably want to do is make two canvases with the same image. Have d be the pixel data for the unblurred image and then blur the data for the other image:

```
var composite = canvas1.getContext("2d").getImageData();
var d = composite.data;
var blurdata = blur(amnt, pixel);
var bd = blurdata.data;
for (var i=0; i<d.length; i+=4) {
    d[i] = 128+(d[i]-bd[i]);
    d[i+1] = 128+(d[i+1]-bd[i+1]);
    d[i+2] = 128+(d[i+2]-bd[i+2]);
}
return composite;
```

I think that should get the job done.

Comment: great, works perfectly. I'm still not completely sure why it does make the same data if d is already defined before the blur takes place, but I'll take a working high pass function... Thanks

Comment: It has to do with JS's hidden type structure. When you create var d it is only a pointer to the array that is referenced by composite.data. That is to say that it does not create a new array as would be the case if you did: var d = new Array();

Comment: Would there be a way to do that then, to make the composite.data actually go into a separate variable? @zach-babb

Comment: If there is I don't know it off the top of my head, and I'm not sure if it would work cross browser with how contexts are implemented. In working with canvases I've found that they don't always behave in a "JavaScripty" way. For example if you made it a new array and then at some later point did context.data = myArray; I'm not sure that would work the way you intended.